# How to switch to docker Compose file v3 for applications running exclusively on my workstation?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

There are a lot of **applications** which **I launch on my workstation using `docker-compose up`**.

Reasons:

- They don't have an installer, or I don't want to use it
- They require a dedicated storage engine to be present
- They require a build process step
- They are created by me and I want them to be easily launched on any workstation
- e.t.c

So what I usually end up with the **following file-structure**:

```
myAppDir
  - docker-compose.yml
  - Dockerfile (not always)
  - someConfigFile
```

And my **docker-compose.yml** is something like this: 
(It can contain 2 or 3 services, but I provide the simplest form that I use)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xyz
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Then when I need to launch the application **I just perform:**

```
docker-compose up # (or with --build)
```

**Recently I tried to add:**

```
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 200M
```

and **got a message:**

> Some services (mysql) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.

**So I tried:**

```
docker stack deploy mystack --compose-file docker-compose.yml
```

**and got message:**

> Ignoring unsupported options: restart
>
> this node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again

This seems more complex that `docker-compose up`.
I saw that I **can use `--compatibility` flag** e.g.

```
docker-compose --compatibility up
```

But the word **compatibility** means to me that **I should soon switch to a new way of launching my apps** locally.

**My question is:** What is the **new procedure that I should follow** for **launching apps on my workstation** using a docker and a descriptor file, in order to **support options present in Compose file v3**?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify memory limits and similar constraints for local containers, you need to use a [version 2 Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/).  This is called out in the [documentation for the `deploy:` `resources:` section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources).  [docker/compose#4513](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513) has some reasonably clear statements that Compose file version 2 is more targeted at local setups and version 3 more at Swarm installations, and that Docker intends to keep supporting both file versions.

Docker has put many options and functions specific to their [Swarm cluster-installation mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) into the core product.  Anything that mentions a "stack", for example, is specific to a Swarm setup.  One consequence of Swarm and plain-Docker things being combined together is that the `deploy:` Docker Compose options only have an effect in Swarm mode.  The [documentation for the `deploy:` key](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy) notes:

> This only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with `docker stack deploy`, and is ignored by `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run`.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: What is the new procedure that I should follow for launching apps on my workstation using a docker and a descriptor file, in order to support options present in Compose file v3?

Docker compose V3 is meant to be used with Docker Swarm deployments, therefore you need to run your Docker in Swarm mode, otherwise just keep using the V2 and it's simpler interface for localhost developments.

For example `restart` is ignored because that responsibility belongs now to the Docker Swarm, not to Docker itself.

Using the compatibility flag it's kind of converting at runtime your V3 compose file into a V2 compose file.

So in short just use V3 if you want to run Docker in Swarm mode to take advantage of all its new features, aka it's kind of a Kubernetes in Docker land.